# Android: How to wrap text by chars? (Not by words) help me

Tags: android

**This is what the app looks like.**

---

I just started

studying Android.

---

**but I want this.**

---

I just started st

udying Android.

---

**I searched for an answer.
This is the search result.**

---

It's a bit hacky, but you could replace spaces with the unicode no-break space character (U+00A0). This will cause your text to be treated as a single string and wrap on characters instead of words.

myString.replace(" ", "\u00A0");

---

**Where should I put that code????**

Comment: What is your goal here? What are you trying to achieve? To print the `\u00A0` value?

Comment: sorry ^^
I have written the question in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want replace string in code, and purpose is only chaning void to nbsp,

You can use @BindingAdapter feature of AAC.

```
@BindingAdapter(“app:text”)
fun TextView.setText(str : String){
    this.text = str.replace(“ “,”\u00A0”)
}
```

in XML,

```
<TextView
    ...
    app:text=“Put your text here”
/>
```

Comment: It's not long since I started studying Android. Am I put that code in MainActivity?

Comment: Then just set textview.setText(str.replace(“ “,”\u00a0”);  when your text is changed each time

Answer (score 0):

Quick way would be replace all spaces with \u00A0 in your xml file

```
<TextView
...
app:text=“Put&#160;your&#160;text&#160;here”
/>
```

&# 160;(without the space) is \u00A0 in html unicode excape syntax (https://unicode-table.com/en/00A0/)

Or when setting via code

```
String myString="put your text here";
textView.setText(myString.replace(" ", "\u00A0"));
```